# How to pause output of integrated powershell in vs code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

On windows, you can pause the output of cmd / PowerShell by clicking on it.

That's really useful for reading logs.

How can I pause the output of the integrated PowerShell in VS Code?

Comment: Does Ctrl-S do anything? Ctrl-Q may resume if so.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: 'That's really useful for reading logs.', huh? Why are you reading logs in the terminal vs opening them in an editor window or sending the output to an editor window or notepad?

Comment: Why not just open the log in the editor vs trying o use the terminal? It's way more flexible, think search in ay direction for words or lines, etc. You can't do that in the terminal, without doing, Select-String or regex string/pattern matches. Thus if you are trying to read the whole log, the terminal is really not the place to be.

Answer (score 1):

Just open your text/logfile in the editor pane directly.

you only need to do this...

```
code D:\Temp\abc.txt
```

... when calling it from the PowerShell consolehost, ISE, VScode, et al, and it will load in the current editor instance you are working in.

I do this daily. Before the advent of VSCode, in the ISE, you call psEdit to do the same.

```
psEdit -filenames D:\Temp\abc.txt
```

***If you are already in VScode, just hit F1, then backspace, then type in the full path to the file.***

This even allows you to see the log updated real-time as text is written and saves to the log.

***Update***

As for this....

> 'I'm reading remote logs from kubernetes which contain ANSI colors.'

... ah, ok, then this is a different use case that you did not qualify in your original post.

I have no kubernetes in my labs and no customer I support currently uses them either.

VSCode provides no means to deal with ANSI colors at this time, in the editor panes for external logs with ANSI, as note per this So Q&A discussion, fro read in logs.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571002/how-can-i-display-ansi-colored-logfile-text-in-vs-code

Support ANSI encoding #92240: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92240

The terminal is a different matter of course. VSCode with regards to theming does support Ansi as defined in the VSCode docs here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Comment: Thank you, that's a great idea. I'd a 100% prefer viewing the logs in a file, the problem is I'm reading remote logs from kubernetes which contain ANSI colors. When I pipe the output from `kubectl logs -f` to a file and view that file with VS Code, the colors show up as escape characters. The output of `console.table` is also unreadable.
e.g. `node -e "console.table([{foo:'bar'}]);" > test.txt; code test.txt`